# MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX syntax error

Tags: database, oracle11g, spatial, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

```
CREATE INDEX test_index ON cola_markets(shape)
   INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

I am creating an index on Oracle Spatial column, following the guidelines here at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objindex.htm#i78196

However, SQL developer keeps complaining about the following error.
[image]

Comment: Always a good idea to specify the exact version of your database installation (i.e. something like "11.2.0.3", not just "11g").

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely the right syntax. I confirm that there is no typing mistake by running it on my database.

On the possibility that this is some oddity due to SQL Developer, can you also try and run the command with plain `sqlplus` ? What do you get ?